# Move certain part of a substring based on width from one column to another

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have these columns let's say

```
+----+------------------------------------+---------+
| ID | ColumnA                            | ColumnB |
+----+------------------------------------+---------+
| 1  | ASDKHASDH SDAJH ASKDHAS HDASDHJ 12 | abcd    |
| 2  | asdjahdasd                         | efghijk |
| 3  | dgfwfbiwbf                         | null    |
| 4  | sdf                                | null    |
+----+------------------------------------+---------+
```

I want a query that says, if `columnA` has LEN of bigger than 30, then move the rest of `columnA` to `columnB` after the last space.

So.. we will end up with

```
+----+---------------------------------+---------+
| ID | ColumnA                         | ColumnB |
+----+---------------------------------+---------+
| 1  | ASDKHASDH SDAJH ASKDHAS HDASDHJ | 12 abcd |
| 2  | asdjahdasd                      | efghijk |
| 3  | dgfwfbiwbf                      | null    |
| 4  | sdf                             | null    |
+----+---------------------------------+---------+
```

Sorry guys maybe I have been not clear enough. Maybe this could help:

Update TableA
set ColumnA = ColumnA - (value of the last substring after the last space),
ColumnB = (value of the last substring from ColumnA after the last space) + ',' + ColumnB
where LEN(ColumnA) > 30

Notice how the 12 on ID 1 is added on ColumnB with the value and a space + columnB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below query, this will give you the first 30 letters in `ColumnA`, and the trailing will append to `ColumnB`

```
SELECT  ID
        ,LEFT(ColumnA,30)   AS  ColumnA
        ,RIGHT(ColumnA,(CASE WHEN LEN(ColumnA) > 30 THEN LEN(ColumnA)-30 ELSE 0 END)) +
            ColumnB AS  ColumnB 
FROM TABLE1
```

If you wand to `ColumnA` to be split after the last empty space when is larger than 30, then please try the below query,

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT  *
            ,(CASE WHEN LEN(ColumnA) > 30
                THEN CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING(ColumnA,31,LEN(ColumnA)))
                ELSE 0 END) AS  FLAG
    FROM    @TABLE

)
SELECT  ID
        ,(CASE WHEN FLAG > 0 THEN LEFT(ColumnA,30+FLAG) 
                            ELSE ColumnA END)   AS  ColumnA
        ,(CASE WHEN FLAG > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(ColumnA,30+FLAG,LEN(ColumnA)) 
                            ELSE '' END )+ ' '+ColumnB AS ColumnB
FROM    CTE
```

Comment: It's not that simple, the OP asks the ColumnA to be split after the last empty space when is larger than 30. Not to be split at the character 30.

Comment: Sorry but can you tell me where's the logic setup to grab the substring from the last space from ColumnA?

Comment: please check the second query , inside the CTE.

Comment: I'm sorry but am I missing something here? The second query inside the CTE just truncates without appending the additional string after the white space into columnB

Comment: @Angie, inside the CTE, there is a column FLAG. If the legth of ColumnA is greater that 30 then FLAG will assigned to the column digit of next while space. And after the CTE will append the remaining text to columnB if the FLAG is greater than 0(FLAG=0 means either ColumnA has length <30 or there is no while space in columnA after 30, Otherwise FLAG contain the excat number where the white space exists in the ColumnA, after 30 digit)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID,SUBSTRING(COlumnA,1,30) AS  ColumnA,
CASE WHEN LEN(COlumnA)>30 
 THEN ColumnB + SUBSTRING(COlumnA,31,LEN(COlumnA)) END AS  ColumnB 
FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`

```
SELECT   
    ID,
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', ColumnA, 30) = 0  THEN ColumnA
    ELSE SUBSTRING(ColumnA, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', ColumnA, 30)) END ColumnA, 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', ColumnA, 30) = 0  THEN ColumnB
    ELSE SUBSTRING(ColumnA, CHARINDEX(' ', ColumnA, 30), LEN(ColumnA)) + ColumnB END AS ColumnB
FROM 
    TBL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression and a combination of string functions `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `SUBSTRING`.

**Query**

```
SELECT id, 
       CASE WHEN Len(ColumnA) > 30 THEN LEFT(ColumnA, 30) 
                 + Substring(ColumnA, 31, Charindex(' ', 
                 RIGHT(ColumnA, Len(columna) - 30)) - 1) 
         ELSE ColumnA END AS ColumnA, 
       CASE WHEN Len(ColumnA) > 30 THEN RIGHT(ColumnA, Len(ColumnA) - 30 
                  - Charindex(' ', RIGHT(ColumnA, Len(AolumnA) - 31)) - 1) 
                  + ' ' + ColumnB
         ELSE ColumnB
       END AS ColumnB 
FROM   [your_table_name];
```